# converting output from reporting software from crosstab to standard tabular shape

Tags: python, pyspark

My data source is a reporting tool. It only outputs a report in crosstab, so there are row groups.
When I output the report to CSV, it looks like this, with the row group on the ID Column:

```
ID,ItemCode,Cost,Quantity
50002242,IT_01,23.00,45
,IL_42,34.00,60
,IM_65,15.00,15
,IS_23,2.00,200
50009999,IT_02,33.00,1
,IG_76,31.00,20
,IP_65,53.00,43
,IA_28,23.00,14
```

I need to import this into spark and using python convert it to a standard table shame. In this case that means ensuring the ID is in each record, so it would look like this:

```
ID,ItemCode,Cost,Quantity
50002242,IT_01,23.00,45
50002242,IL_42,34.00,60
50002242,IM_65,15.00,15
50002242,IS_23,2.00,200
50009999,IT_02,33.00,1
50009999,IG_76,31.00,20
50009999,IP_65,53.00,43
50009999,IA_28,23.00,14
```

Appreciate any expertise in how this can be done in pyspark python. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have to use PySpark for this? Essentially, your data is CSV albeit that the first column value is sometimes empty. So all you have to do is replace the empty value with the previous non-empty value

Comment: not really though, the reporting platform adds a comma to the beginning of each row under the row with the ID, which makes it a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption: there are only 3 missing rows between each ID**

*Since this is some sort of table with row groups, I suppose this could be the case*

```py
(df
    # creating fake ID so we can reserve the initial order for later rankings
    .withColumn('fid', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

    # get "next ID (#1)" based on ID
    .withColumn('ID_1', F.lag('ID')  .over(W.orderBy('fid')))

    # get "next ID (#2)" based on ID #1
    .withColumn('ID_2', F.lag('ID_1').over(W.orderBy('fid')))

    # get "next ID (#3)" based on ID #2
    .withColumn('ID_3', F.lag('ID_2').over(W.orderBy('fid')))

    # find first not null ID based on the IDs
    .withColumn('ID', F.coalesce('ID', 'ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3'))

    # drop temp columns
    .drop('fid', 'ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3')

    .show()
)

# Output
# +--------+--------+-----+--------+
# |      ID|ItemCode| Cost|Quantity|
# +--------+--------+-----+--------+
# |50002242|   IT_01|23.00|      45|
# |50002242|   IL_42|34.00|      60|
# |50002242|   IM_65|15.00|      15|
# |50002242|   IS_23| 2.00|     200|
# |50009999|   IT_02|33.00|       1|
# |50009999|   IG_76|31.00|      20|
# |50009999|   IP_65|53.00|      43|
# |50009999|   IA_28|23.00|      14|
# +--------+--------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my earlier comment, this looks like CSV format except for the occasional missing column which, when absent, has the implied value of the previous actual column value. So, I create a file containing these data:-

```
ID,ItemCode,Cost,Quantity<br>
50002242,IT_01,23.00,45<br>
,IL_42,34.00,60<br>
,IM_65,15.00,15<br>
,IS_23,2.00,200<br>
50009999,IT_02,33.00,1<br>
,IG_76,31.00,20<br>
,IP_65,53.00,43<br>
,IA_28,23.00,14<br>
```

Then this code:-

```
CSV = []
prev = None
with open('/Users/andy/ct.txt') as ct:
    for line in ct:
        t = line.strip().split(',')
        if t[0] == '':
            t[0] = prev
        else:
            prev = t[0]
        CSV.append(','.join(t))
print(CSV)
```

...will build a list of strings that can be treated as real CSV